# What do I need to learn in 3DS Max?

Tags: 3dsmax

I have joined a 3ds Max course. What are the diiferent part of 3ds Max which I need to learn?

He was saying that he will teach me architecture. What are the divisions of 3ds max, so that I know which things to learn?

Also, where do vray, mental ray, particle effects, and character modellings stand in 3ds max?

Is architecture alone going to be enough for me?

Comment: what you need to learn depends on what you're trying to do. explain that please

Comment: -1, too vague and too many questions.

Comment: I edited your question to try and make it easier to read. I can't tell what you meant in the second paragraph.

Comment: i can't understand why more experienced people can't answer newbies vague question properly while newbie answer them perfectly, just like Arvin

Comment: Answering a bad question well doesn't change the fact that it was a bad question. There's even a badge called Reversal specifically because of that.

Comment: In fact now that I looked at your profile I see multiple vague questions about 3ds Max. If you want us to stop voting down your questions then you should learn to ask better questions.  Read the site's FAQ for more information about that.

Comment: Its really irony for me that in order to ask better questions i first need to get answer of my vague questions , which can clear my wrong concepts , so that i can ask better questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No one can give you an answer to this other than yourself. You need to ask yourself - What do you wanna be? What do you wanna do? What do you like?

Typically these are the areas you might want to consider specializing in when it comes to 3D:

- Modelling
- Animation
- Texturing
- Lighting
- Rendering (which is where vray and mental ray come to play)

alternatively, of course you can go ahead and learn all of these things!

If you want to become an architect you may want to consider Modelling, texturing and lighting, and possibly rendering. (Although for architecture there are better solutions than 3DSmax, such as AutoCAD)

If you like Disney/Pixar films like Toy Story you might want to consider Modelling and Animation.

The same thing also applies to game development (except maybe lighting and rendering). Game characters need to be modeled, they need to be textured, they need to be animated. Whichever one you want to learn to do is up to you

Also, 3DSMax does not specialize in any one of these areas. It's great for all of them.

Comment: 3ds Max Design is a spin on 3ds Max specifically intended for architects actually. Although AutoCAD is more useful for exact blueprints, 3ds Max is commonly used for architectural renderings. heck that is the entire point of this blog http://3dsmaxrendering.blogspot.com/

Comment: ah, I wasn't aware of the Design version.